# Is it possible to make the selenium Webdriver(Java) to verify if certain js. calls are made from the site when entering a page?

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

it possible to make the test automation tool to verify if certain js. calls are made from the site when entering a page?

Is there any method from which i will get all the list of java script called?

Comment: What do you mean by js calls? Do you mean HTTP request or function call stacks?